# How to overload class method with two template parameters, so I can use std::function as one of them?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, overloading, std-function

I need some help with working with templates.
I have code like this,
it's class holding two vectors of std::function object, and a method that pushes some function (bind, lambda, or functor) in one of them:

```
typedef std::function<int(int)> unFuncPtr;
typedef std::function<int(int, int)> binFuncPtr;

class Operations
{
public:
    template <size_t argsCount, class T>
    void RegisterOperator(T fn) {
        if (argsCount == 1) {
            m_unaryOperations.push_back(fn);
        }
        if (argsCount == 2) {
            m_binaryOperations.push_back(fn);
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<unFuncPtr> m_binaryOperations;
    std::vector<binFuncPtr> m_unaryOperations;
```

I wanted this code to push, for example, lambda with two argements in `m_binaryOperations` or lambda with only one argument to `m_unaryOperations` calling method `RegisterOperator` like this:

```
Operations operations;
operations.RegisterOperator<1>([](int x) {return x * x; })
operations.RegisterOperator<2>([](int x, int y) {return x + y; })
```

But it gives me a funtion-style-cast error.
As I understand it's because of interpreting `class T` in two different ways in one function.

How can I modify the code to call the method with template parameter 1 or 2 for `argsCount`, so it will be known what type is `class T` and to what vector function from the argument must be pushed?

I tried different ways to solve this problem.

The first one is to overload templates inside the class like this:

```
template <size_t argsCount, class T>
void RegisterOperator(T fn) {
}

template<>
void RegisterOperator<1>(unFunPtr fn) {
    m_unaryOperations.push_back(fn);
}

template<>
void RegisterOperator<2>(binFunPtr fn) {
    m_binaryOperations.push_back(fn);
}
```

But debugging showed me that it won't even go inside overloaded functions with the examples I wrote upper in question.

The second one is to overload templates inside the class like this:

```
template<class T = unFunPtr>
void RegisterOperator<1>(T fn) {
    m_unaryOperations.push_back(fn);
}

template<class T = binFunPtr>
void RegisterOperator<2>(T fn) {
    m_binaryOperations.push_back(fn);
}
```

I thought the default template lets me define only `argsCount` in the template when I'm calling the method, but it causes a lot of errors.

Hoping for your help.

Comment: If you have a C++20 compiler, you can do `if constexpr(requires(){ m_unaryOperations.push_back(fn); }` and avoid having `size_t argsCount`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have a typo here:

```
std::vector<unFuncPtr> m_binaryOperations;
std::vector<binFuncPtr> m_unaryOperations;
```

It should be:

```
std::vector<unFuncPtr> m_unaryOperations;
std::vector<binFuncPtr> m_binaryOperations;
```

Second, even then it wouldn't compile, since with "ordinary" `if`, both branches needs to be compilable. You can resolve the problem with `if constexpr` if you have C++17 available:

```
void RegisterOperator(T fn) {
  if constexpr (argsCount == 1) 
    m_unaryOperations.push_back(fn);

  if constexpr (argsCount == 2) 
    m_binaryOperations.push_back(fn);
}
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/bbqs7Knbd

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It works. But what about version of code with overrided templates, why doesn't it work?

Comment: @Jr_vv That is not overloading (nor overrriding), that is specialization. AFAIK, you cannot specialize a member function template at a class scope. See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/51767514/580083 for details.